# Powershell: Create folder with today's date

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create one folder named test_20131001 like today's date.

```
$today = (get-date).Date  

$dateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $today

New-Item C:\Desktop\Access\test_$dateStr
```

But every time I run this script, This gives me:

```
type:
```

I don't know why this is asking type:? and I am not sure this is correct way of doing this.

Comment: May I suggest a little simplification, even though it's unrelated to your actual question? `Get-Date` already supports formatting, so you can create your date string in a single step like this: `$dateStr = Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd'`.

Comment: You can type `Get-Help <cmdletname> -Examples` from Powershell for example usages of this and other cmdlets.  Very helpful for usage issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new item type parameter is missing.  Try this:

```
New-Item C:\Desktop\Access\test_$dateStr -ItemType directory
```